# JMeter - Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to specify programmatically the number of threads from within the Thread Group?
My scenario: I need to run two Thread Groups. Each group will read files that specify the number of threads for that group to run. The groups should run concurrently.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties.

For ex:

In the number of threads field, you can set like this
`$(__P(usercount)}`

When you run the test through command line, you can pass the value as shown here

`jmeter -n -t test.jmx -Jusercount=10`

Now the test will run for 10 users.

You can also use `$(__P(usercount,5)}`
That is, if the property value is passed to the test, then it will use it, otherwise, it will take the default value which is 5.

Comment: Thanks, Vinoth. After I asked this question, I found your great Property File Reader.

Comment: @Vladimir. Oh I see, Glad that you find that useful :)